# Compiler error on Registering a TemporalTableFunction as a Function

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I'm following Flink's [Defining Temporal Table Function](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/table/streaming/temporal_tables.html#defining-temporal-table-function) example, and the compiler refuses to take that code:

```
TemporalTableFunction rates = 
    ratesHistory.createTemporalTableFunction("r_proctime", "r_currency");
tEnv.registerFunction("Rates", rates);
```

My compiler tells me "The method registerFunction(String, ScalarFunction) in the type TableEnvironment is not applicable for the arguments (String, TemporalTableFunction)"

I have scoured the source code [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/0ab1549f52f1f544e8492757c6b0d562bf50a061/flink-table/flink-table-planner/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/table/api/StreamTableEnvironment.scala) and [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/0ab1549f52f1f544e8492757c6b0d562bf50a061/flink-table/flink-table-planner/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/table/api/TableEnvironment.scala), and indeed no registerFunction has the TemporalTableFunction signature. Only the ScalarFunction type. I'm baffled as to why it would compile; but [they do have a test on it](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/5d8e4d5b630b5e7da99ac879d102dbb18d6b6ac6/flink-table/flink-table-planner/src/test/scala/org/apache/flink/table/runtime/stream/sql/TemporalJoinITCase.scala).

I just can't navigate where the TemporalJoinITCase is getting its registerFunction from.

Flink 1.7.1 with scala 2.11, and the following artifacts: flink-core, flink-java, flink-clients_, flink-streaming-java_, flink-table_, flink-streaming-scala_, flink-json, flink-runtime-web_.

I don't know well how Scala works; could it be some trait that I'm missing from another artifact?

Best regard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

I needed to import StreamTableEnvironment from a specific package: org.apache.flink.table.api.java.StreamTableEnvironment. My autocompletion was not being properly update in time, which made me think there was no proper method. But it is there.